# Reading a Word doc in PHP and parse its content to store properly in database

Tags: php, parsing, doc

I am using PHP to generate a system where the user will get a question followed by 4 options each may contain a text and an image associated.

The data operators have a doc file of questions which contains a table of question options and images.

Somehow I need to parse that doc file and extract the text out of it and store it in database and images in appropriate folder.

How this can be done?

Note: I am using PHP on a Linux server.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646445/read-word-document-in-php

Comment: That post doesn't provide an answer
It has one for docx file which is different from doc file