# How to read word document and put annotation using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter for uploading word documents.
I am using read_file for reading word document.

```
public function open_files(){
    $data['string'] = read_file('./uploads/uwtest.docx');
    $this->load->view('openfiles',$data);       
}
```

But I am getting different format as output.Something like this

```
PK,��H]m�Cd word/media/section_image1.jpg��gTSͷ�C�� �� H�  
�tA�z�ދґ"�t����%1�^C/��I@ ��۾���g��5��>g=�33kֹ��Z0�hhk���/�� 
�U�sv��B��:w@r="�n���<@ 
@L�W#�_����d��$��d����T�ם����������G�4Դ'_������QS�SP��u�p�`
```

Comment: Sure, this is expected behavior. You are just opening the Word file and looking at its binary content.

Comment: docs is a binary format, you cannot just read it as a text file, need to parse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646445/read-word-document-in-php

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with that Word document?

Comment: I need to add annotations on the word document.For example, someone uploads the document and other users add their analysis on the different part of the word document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so far, I get this only

```
function read_docx($filename){
 $striped_content = '';
 $content = '';
 if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) return false;

 $zip = zip_open($filename);
 if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

 while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

    if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

    if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;

  $content.=zip_entry_read($zip_entry,zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

    zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
}
 zip_close($zip);      
 $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
 $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
 $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

 return $striped_content;
}
```

But it will return only content.I am looking forward to how to get images and same formatting as in word.