# php extract text from word file pages wise

Tags: php

I want to extract text from an msword file (eg: .docx) to use the content of msword file in my PHP script.

Is it possible to get *all pages* in an array of php? Like

```
$array = [
   [0] => 'content here......',
   [1] => 'content here......',
   [2] => 'content here......',
];
```

where index 0 is page one, index 1 is page two and so on.

Comment: What have you tried? Got this from a simple google... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646445/read-word-document-in-php

Comment: i've tried that but it read the whole document i want an array for pages

Comment: you need to check out a plugin that support these kinda things.... mostlikely it exist you just need to google it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it Myself i used a class

https://github.com/abhihub/EDUSITE/blob/master/DocxConversion.php

```
$docObj = new DocxConversion("example.docx");
$docText= $docObj->convertToText(1);
```

and i got my desired result

Posting this answer because maybe someone needs it in Future

Comment: Hello, Please let me know is there way to convert this docx file to pdf file.

Comment: I don't see it's returning docx' pages in your code? It supposed to split doxc file pages and return it as an array!