# I want to upload word document and view data in a text box using laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5, laravel-8

I created a form that user can enter the data in a text box and generate word document. Now I want to upload a word document and view the data in a text box. how can I do that using php in Laravel?

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: I created a form that user can add data and generate a word file. now i want to upload word file and view data in a text box.

Comment: Please add that to your code. Add your attempt code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

[this is how far I done this project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmjQ6.png)

I crated a form and generate a word file now i want to upload this word file and view details in text box

Comment: You should update this on your question section not submit this as an answer. 
Also, the previous commenter was asking for you to add the codes you have tried to parse the uploaded word document. You can start your research using the term "parse word document php/laravel". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646445/read-word-document-in-php and PHPWord package might help you for it too.