# Printing Word Doc using exec()

Tags: php

Using the instructions [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=10600), I can successfully print a Word doc using the command line on the webserver. Eg:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office12/WINWORD.EXE" c:\temp\test.docx /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit
```

However I now want to use PHP to run this command. Eg:

```
echo exec('"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office12/WINWORD.EXE" c:\temp\test.docx /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit');
```

When I run the PHP file through the webserver in the browser, using Task Manager I can see that WINWORD.EXE *32 starts and runs, however it stays running and does not print or self-quit.

PHP naturally returns a timeout error. The command line method successfully runs within 15 seconds, so I don't think the time length is the problem.

Comment: Use `COM("word.application")` instead, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144023/opening-word-document-with-read-mode-using-php/7144200#7144200

Answer (score 1):

try

```
echo exec('"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office12/WINWORD.EXE" c:\\temp\\test.docx /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit');
```

it could be due to unescaped `\`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I gave it a go, but it didn't make any difference. I do agree with you that the problem could be more to do with not locating the file. Do you think the path is relative to the php script or WINWORD.EXE?